# Categorical interpretation of quantum double $D(A,B,\eta)$

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, drinfeld-center

It is known that the Drinfel'd double $D(A)$ of a Hopf algebra $A$ is characterized by the following two properties:

1. The category of left $D(A)$-modules $_{D(A)}\mathcal{M}$ is equivalent to the category of Yetter-Drinfeld modules $_A\mathcal{YD}^A$.
2. The category of left $D(A)$-modules $_{D(A)}\mathcal{M}$ is equivalent to the center  $\mathcal{Z}(_A\mathcal{M})$ of $_A\mathcal{M}$.

In general, for a (possibly degenerate) skew-Hopf pairing $\eta:A\otimes B \to k$ one can define a quantum double $D(A,B,\eta)$, s.t. the Drinfel'd double is the special case $B=A^*$ (see [KS], 8.2.1). Is there a categorical interpretation of $D(A,B,\eta)$ in analogy to $D(A)$?

[KS] Klymik, Schmüdgen - Hopf algebras and their representations

**EDIT:** My first guess is that $_{D(A,B,\eta)}\mathcal{M}$ is equivalent to the category of both left $A$-modules and right $B$-modules $M$, satisfying
$$\eta(a_{(1)},b_{(1)})(a_{(2)}.m).b_{(2)}=\eta(a_{(2)},b_{(2)})a_{(1)}.(m.b_{(1)})$$